# How to make BufferedInputStream Serializable?

Tags: java

I need to make java BufferedInputStream Serializable. Are there any alternatives or any other way to implement it?

Do yo see any issue in this implementation

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class SerializableBufferedInputStream extends BufferedInputStream implements Serializable
{
  public SerializableBufferedInputStream(InputStream in)
  {
    super(in);
  }

  public SerializableBufferedInputStream(InputStream in, int size)
  {
    super(in, size);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to serialise an input stream in the first place?

Comment: Why do you want to serialize it? You can just create a new `BufferedInputStream`.

Comment: I have a ListBean which has input stream and when ejb passivation it throws NotSerializableException due to input stream.

Comment: Do you need to serialize data of input stream or you can read data again after deserialization?

Comment: Please add your code: how did you created the BIS, how to serialize.

Comment: @Piro Yes I need to serialize data of the stream

Answer (score 0):

First of all, BufferedInputStream  Creates a BufferedInputStream and saves its argument, the input stream in, for later use.
but you are saying Serializable which means converting the state of an object into a byte stream
so why do you need to convert it ??

This thing may help you check (Provide your Code in case you want other than this)

```
public class MainClass {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Punk obj1 = new Punk("A");
    Punk obj2 = new Punk("B");
    Punk obj3 = new Punk("V");
    ObjectOutputStream objectOut = new ObjectOutputStream(new BufferedOutputStream(
            new FileOutputStream("C:/punkObjects.bin")));

    objectOut.writeObject(obj1); // Write object
    objectOut.writeObject(obj2); // Write object
    objectOut.writeObject(obj3); // Write object
    objectOut.close(); // Close the output stream

    ObjectInputStream objectIn = null;
    int objectCount = 0;
    punk object = null;

    objectIn = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(
            "C:/punkObjects.bin")));

    // Read from the stream until we hit the end
    while (objectCount < 3) {
        object = (punk) objectIn.readObject();
        objectCount++;
        System.out.println(object);
    }

    objectIn.close();

}
}

class Punk implements Serializable {

String str;

public Punk(String s) {
    str = s;
}
}
```